# Macports issues after Mountain Lion upgrade

Tags: macos, upgrade, macports

After upgrading Lion to *Mountain Lion*, the *MacPorts* system seems broken.

Refering to the [*MacPorts*'s migration page](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration), the best solution seems to unistall all and reinstall all the ports.

Is there a simpler/less drastic solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I fix it (after Mountain Lion update):

- install the latest [*MacPorts* DMG dedicated to Mountain Lion](http://www.macports.org/install.php) over the old one;
- install the latest *Xcode* version from the *AppStore* (it doesn't update by itself!);
- launch *Xcode* and agree to the licence;
- in *Xcode*'s *Preferences*, at the *Download*'s tab, in the *Components* section, install *Command Line Tools* ([as since Xcode 4.3](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html));
- **don't forget** that you must read and accept licence for it, this is possible after running the following command in the terminal: `sudo xcodebuild -license`.

  - Without this step, if you try to use `sudo port install [something]` or others, you'll have the following return: **[Error: org.macports.build for port libunwind-headers returned: command execution failed](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/35150)**
- in terminal:

  - `sudo port selfupdate`
  - `sudo port upgrade outdated`

After that, everything works except *MongoDB*, After some research, I found [this article (How to upgrade MacPorts to OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion)](http://philfreo.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-macports-to-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion/) by [Phil Freo](http://philfreo.com/).

Thanks to this article, which reassured me in my approach, I also found the solution to my last issue:

> Everything finished and worked properly except *MongoDB*. Currently there is an incompatibility between boost 1.50 and MongoDB which can be resolved with these two commands, assuming boost 1.49 was previously installed on your machine:

- `sudo port activate boost @1.49.0_0`
- `sudo port -n install mongodb`

Comment: The mongodb solution proposed only works if mongodb was already installed prior to installing Mountain Lion. If, on the other hand you wish to install mongodb fresh, this will not help you because the mongodb configurations upgrades boost to 1.5.0 which breaks mongodb! It seems like the only workaround is to wait for the maintainers of the mongodb port to resolve the boost issue.

Comment: MongoDB issue here: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/35726

Comment: Here is the original ticket: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/35118

Comment: The ticket for the Boost problem in MongoDB is here: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4314